# Merge PHP array having same keys different values

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to merge arrays with the same keys with different values, like below.

Input:

```
$array1 = array('1933' => array(
    'nid' => '492811',
    'title' => 'NEW TITLE',
    'field_link_single_url' => 'abc',
    'field_link_single_title' => 'test' 
    ));
    
$array2 = array('1933' => array(
    'nid' => '492811',
    'title' => 'NEW TITLE',
    'field_link_single_url' => 'xyz',
    'field_link_single_title' => 'abcd' 
    ));
```

Expected output to be:

```
Array
(
    [nid] => 492811
    [title] => NEW TITLE
    [field_link_single_url] => [
          [0] => 'abc',
          [1] => 'xyz'
    ]
    [field_link_single_title] => [
          [0] => 'test',
          [1] => 'abcd'
    ]
)
```

I have tried `array_merge` and `array_merge_recursive` but it does not work as expected.

Output of `array_merge_recursive($array1[1933], $array2[1933])` it is creating duplicates keys having same value

```
Array
(
    [nid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 492811
            [1] => 492811
        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hal  Louchheim
            [1] => Hal  Louchheim
        )

    [field_link_single_url] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
            [1] => xyz
        )

    [field_link_single_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => abcd
        )

)
```

Comment: Is that a typo? `array_merge_recursive` should do what you need

Comment: @AndyHolmes No...? https://3v4l.org/FSV7Y

Comment: `array_merge_recursive` can't turn string into array.

Comment: It is possible to use `array_merge_recursive` if you would leave first level of tree (with key "1933"). As long as you need to keep this structure there is not native one-line function and you have to write your own function and iterate it by your own.

Comment: Do you already know which keys will change and should turn into arrays or the code should automatically detect which keys changes and which ones remain the same?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Do `array1` and `array2` have more elements then shown in your example, or only the `1933`?

Comment: @AndyHolmes I have updated the question with `array_merge_recursive` output

Comment: @Michel just `1933`

Comment: @Andreas OP originally had `array_recursive_merge` not `array_merge_recursive` hence my typo comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some assumption. If these assumptions are not valid, you should add some additional checks:

- Both $array1 and $array2 are really arrays
- Both $array1 and $array2 have the exact same keys
- The values inside $array1 and $array2 are primitive types, not complex objects (the `===` operator would not work to compare objects or arrays)

```php
function mergeArrayValues($array1, $array2) {
  $output = [];
  foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $output[$key] = $array1[$key] === $array2[$key] 
       ? $array1[$key]
       : [ $array1[$key], $array2[$key] ]
  }
  return $output;
}

mergeArrayValues($array1[1933], $array2[1933])
```